# Apps not showing .How to reinstall the factory apps

Tags: applications, settings, system-apps

Ok so i rooted my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 inch tablet and i wanted to get rid of some useless factory apps that i never used but after i did that and exited kingroot i had no applications on my screen..my wallpaper is still here,the bar on top from where u can activate wifi, gps etc.(i dont know how its called sorry) is still functional (and i can go to settings from there but it doesnt work every time) and the digital buttons are working perfectly..it seems like everything works fine exept that when i restart i get the com.android.phone error. I accessed google from the task killer from where i can also go to the app manager witch works good also.
PS:Factory reset doesnt resolve the problem.

Comment: I also noticed that if i press the home button or the go back button in order to leave to the home screen it doesnt work..i have to kill the current tab in order to get to my actuall "home screen"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you removed the launcher (homescreen) along with some other critical stuff.

For now, go to Settings and turn on USB Debugging, plug into your PC, install appropriate drivers, and sideload another launcher app, so that you can see all your apps and backup data. After backing up, flash a [factory firmware](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/) via Odin from your PC to get a fresh start (you do need to root again).